# Add n days to a date token

Tags: linux, date-utility

My issue as follows: consider I have a token `$d=20140607` and I want to add 7 days to it.

I tried `date -d "$d+7 days"` but it is not working. It throws this error

> date: invalid date `20160407+7days'

Any little bit of info is appreciated.

Comment: What OS/version are you using? Does `date --version` yield a GNU version of date?

Comment: Hi Lars, Thanks for the help. date (GNU coreutils) 5.93

Comment: try with a space before `+`

Comment: Still the same "date: invalid date `20160407 +7 days'"

Comment: GNU coreutils 5.93 was released in November 2005. You could check "man date" to see if your version supports this syntax. Though, you might consider updating your version of coreutils.

Comment: Have you tried inputting the value of the token directly to make sure that this syntax works in your version of coreutils/date? Have you tried a different date or syntax?  Try `date -d "today +7 days"`, `date --date="20160407 +7days"`, or `date -d "April 7, 2016 +7days"`.

Comment: Thank you Ryan! It works when I tried directly put some value like '20140607', but the issue comes, when I try the same syntax with token

Comment: Which shell? What does `echo "d=$d"` say?

Answer (score 1):

```
date -d "$d + 7 days"
```

Modern versions of GNU coreutils understand this without the spaces, but older versions require spaces (at least the space after the `+`).